# Increase Speed Performance on C# PrintWindow() in PowerShell?

Tags: c#, powershell, screenshot

I have successfully implemented C# code of PrintWindow to use within PowerShell (below), but I am wondering if I can speed this process up. It currently takes on average 80ms to perform the PrintWindow method. I would like to either cut this in half or drastically reduce the time it takes to perform PrintWindow picture taking.

Can someone please provide some insight and possibly examples/changes that I can directly plug into my existing code to increase the speed of PrintWindow?

**Current PrintWindow Method:**

```
        $PrintWindowCode = @'
        using System; 
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Drawing.Imaging;

        public class ScreenCapture
        {

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

        public Bitmap PrintWindow(IntPtr hwnd)    
        {       
            int PW_CLIENTONLY = 0x1;
            int PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT = 0x2; 
            RECT rc;        
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            using (Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {        
                IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();       

                try
                {
                    PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, PW_CLIENTONLY | PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT);
                }
                finally
                {
                    gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
                    gfxBmp.Dispose();
                }
            }

            string acPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string currentDir = acPath;    
            System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(currentDir);

            bmp.Save("TestOutput.tif", ImageFormat.Tiff);

            try {
                    return bmp;
            }
            finally {
                    bmp.Dispose();
                    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(acPath);
            }
     
        }


        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            private int _Left;
            private int _Top;
            private int _Right;
            private int _Bottom;

            public RECT(RECT Rectangle) : this(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom)
            {
            }
            public RECT(int Left, int Top, int Right, int Bottom)
            {
                _Left = Left;
                _Top = Top;
                _Right = Right;
                _Bottom = Bottom;
            }

            public int X {
                get { return _Left; }
                set { _Left = value; }
            }
            public int Y {
                get { return _Top; }
                set { _Top = value; }
            }
            public int Left {
                get { return _Left; }
                set { _Left = value; }
            }
            public int Top {
                get { return _Top; }
                set { _Top = value; }
            }
            public int Right {
                get { return _Right; }
                set { _Right = value; }
            }
            public int Bottom {
                get { return _Bottom; }
                set { _Bottom = value; }
            }
            public int Height {
                get { return _Bottom - _Top; }
                set { _Bottom = value + _Top; }
            }
            public int Width {
                get { return _Right - _Left; }
                set { _Right = value + _Left; }
            }
            public Point Location {
                get { return new Point(Left, Top); }
                set {
                    _Left = value.X;
                    _Top = value.Y;
                }
            }
            public Size Size {
                get { return new Size(Width, Height); }
                set {
                    _Right = value.Width + _Left;
                    _Bottom = value.Height + _Top;
                }
            }

            public static implicit operator Rectangle(RECT Rectangle)
            {
                return new Rectangle(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
            }
            public static implicit operator RECT(Rectangle Rectangle)
            {
                return new RECT(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom);
            }
            public static bool operator ==(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
            {
                return Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
            }
            public static bool operator !=(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
            {
                return !Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "{Left: " + _Left + "; " + "Top: " + _Top + "; Right: " + _Right + "; Bottom: " + _Bottom + "}";
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return ToString().GetHashCode();
            }

            public bool Equals(RECT Rectangle)
            {
                return Rectangle.Left == _Left && Rectangle.Top == _Top && Rectangle.Right == _Right && Rectangle.Bottom == _Bottom;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object Object)
            {
                if (Object is RECT) {
                    return Equals((RECT)Object);
                } else if (Object is Rectangle) {
                    return Equals(new RECT((Rectangle)Object));
                }

                return false;
            }
          }

        }

'@

        # Loads/Adds User Add-Type (With correct Assemblies)
        Add-type $PrintWindowCode -ReferencedAssemblies 'System.Windows.Forms','System.Drawing' 

        # Creates the object for the Function (ScreenShotAC.ScreenCapture)
        $ScreenCapture = New-Object ScreenCapture

        # Use PrintWindow to grab screenshot
        $ScreenCapture.PrintWindow(((Get-Process -Name javaw).MainWindowHandle))
```

I have looked into some C# memory stream approaches and did stumble upon created methods that speed up the bitmap processing of loading the image/file. But, I just lacking the understanding on how to properly implement this.

Comment: if you don't need the use of the bitmap, you can discard it. You have redundant directory operations where you set the current directory, to the current directory. Graphics object disposal inside the `PrintWindow` function may not be necessary immediately after using it. The using statement will already dispose of it once it goes out of scope. Explicitly calling `gfxBmp.Dispose()` can be removed. Saving to a JPEG or PNG is generally faster than saving as a TIFF since it usually results in larger sizes. And this question really belongs in codereview.

Answer (score 3):

What I recommend you to do if you want to improve your code load time is to compile that C# code ahead of time so you don't have to do it at runtime each time.

`Add-Type` allows you to specify an output assembly, so essentially, you would do this process just once. Below is the code to compile your C# code into an assembly with some extra logic to make it compatible with PowerShell 5.1 and PowerShell 7+.

```bash
# CSharp code goes here (should stay same as before)
$PrintWindowCode = '...'

# Define the absolute path where to store your assembly:
$assemblyPath = 'path\to\destination\assembly.dll'

$refAssemblies = @(
    'System.Windows.Forms'
    'System.Drawing'
    
    # this is a needed workaround for pwsh 7+
    # see: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9599
    if ($IsCoreCLR) {
        'System.Drawing.Common'
        $pwshLocation = Split-Path -Path ([psobject].Assembly.Location) -Parent
        $pwshRefAssemblyPattern = [IO.Path]::Combine($pwshLocation, 'ref', '*.dll')
        (Get-Item -Path $pwshRefAssemblyPattern).FullName
    }
)

$addTypeSplat = @{
    ReferencedAssemblies = $refAssemblies
    OutputAssembly       = $assemblyPath
    TypeDefinition       = $PrintWindowCode
}

Add-Type @addTypeSplat
```

Now that you have your assembly you can update your code to simply import it from its path.

```bash
# Define the absolute path where the assembly is stored:
$assemblyPath = 'path\to\theStored\assembly.dll'

# Loads/Adds User Add-Type (With correct Assemblies)
Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath

# Creates the object for the Function (ScreenShotAC.ScreenCapture)
$ScreenCapture = [ScreenCapture]::new()

# Use PrintWindow to grab screenshot
$ScreenCapture.PrintWindow((Get-Process -Name javaw).MainWindowHandle)
```

---

If, for some reason, **you don't want to load the assembly from a file**, then the next step, *which I personally do not recommend*, is to hardcode the Base64 string containing the compiled code. **Be aware, this technique might get flagged by some AVs and is totally understandable.**

```bash
# Define the absolute path where the assembly is stored:
$assemblyPath = 'path\to\theStored\assembly.dll'
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($assemblyPath)) |
    Set-Clipboard
```

Now that you have the Base64 string in your clipboard, you can paste it in your script (*hardcode it*) and then the next runs you simply decode the Base64 string and load the bytes:

```bash
# This will be a very very big base64 string, shortening it for demo purposes
$b64 = 'TVqQAAMAAAAEAAAA//8AALgAAAA.......'

# decode the b64 and load it
$null = [Reflection.Assembly]::Load([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($b64))

# rest of the code remains the same:
$ScreenCapture = [ScreenCapture]::new()

# Use PrintWindow to grab screenshot
$ScreenCapture.PrintWindow((Get-Process -Name javaw).MainWindowHandle)
```